# PHP check if value exists in multi-tier array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a PHP array, assigned to `$terms`, from Wordpress that looks like this when printed:

```
Array ( [0] => WP_Term Object ( 
        [term_id] => 19 
        [name] => Tshirts 
        [slug] => tshirts 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 19 
        [taxonomy] => clothes 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 6 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
        [1] => WP_Term Object ( 
        [term_id] => 30 
        [name] => Pants 
        [slug] => pants 
        [term_group] => 0 
        [term_taxonomy_id] => 30 
        [taxonomy] => clothes 
        [description] => 
        [parent] => 0 
        [count] => 12 
        [filter] => raw 
    ) 
)
```

I am trying to use `in_array()` to check if a value exists within the array, but I am having trouble since the array contains more parameters than just the categories. Let's say I want to see if pants exists in this array, here's what I've tried:

```
if (in_array('pants', $terms)) {
    echo "Pants in array";
}
```

How can I modify this if statement so that it checks if `pants` exists as a `slug` in this array?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if value exists in multidimensional array using array\_search and array\_column not returning values of Array\[0\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38054669/check-if-value-exists-in-multidimensional-array-using-array-search-and-array-col)

Comment: Your array values is "WP_Term Object", you must have arrays not array of objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array_search` and `array_column` in combination. You'll want to turn the `WP_Term` object to an array too. Luckily it has a `to_array()` method for that so we can use `array_map` to convert them en masse in our function before searching the items:

```
var_dump(termsContainsSlug('pants', $terms)); // bool(true)

function termsContainsSlug($slug, $terms) {
    $terms = array_map(function($term) { return $term->to_array(); }, $terms);
    return array_search($slug, array_column($terms, 'slug')) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you should transform each object to an array and then test if there are any 'pants' value in.

```
foreach($terms as $term) {
    if (in_array('pants', (array)$term)) {
        echo "Pants in array";
    }
}
```

This should transform WP_Term Object -> array

```
(array)$term
```